# How to substitute a query value into a command argument

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I need to call a shell process but pass a value in from a database query for the fourth argument, I've tried everything under the sun to get this to work including using `%` and `{{`, etc. This works if I hardcode the key in the last argument:

```
document = get_object_or_404(Document, document_id=buid)

stream = subprocess.check_output(['multichain-cli','chain1','liststreamkeyitems','stream1','14fee98fd60e42afbcb0c5bb3e57847c'])
```

But if I try and pass it in using various methods such as:

```
stream = subprocess.check_output(['multichaincli','chain1','liststreamkeyitems','stream1','%i' % document.document_id])
```

It wont work. Any help would be much appreciated, I've spent all afternoon trying to google the solution but I have a feeling I am phrasing the question wrongly.

Comment: You should show what you've tried. Where is your database query? What value are you trying to substitute?

Comment: I've edited it to include the actual code that works and what I've tried to substitute in the value, hopefully this is clearer now.

Comment: And I should now also point out that document.document_id is a UUID which I now think is part of the problem.